# Hive Jdbc connection errors with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am writing Jdbc program to connect with hive database but
I am getting error as:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration  at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createUnderlyingTransport(HiveConnection.java:418)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:438)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:182)
>     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)  at
>   com.nucsoft.client.HiveJdbc.main(HiveJdbc.java:31)

Comment: Check your dependencies/jars...you are missing one of those

Comment: I am using hadoop-2.7.3 version so can anybody tell me from where i  can download hadoop-core-2.7.3 jar

Comment: The libraries are not present in the classpath. If you are running the program in a machine where hive is already installed, then you can use the command - hive --service jar <jar-containing-your-program> <Main class>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `Configuration` class. `hadoop-core` jar was changed to `hadoop-common` in Hadoop 2. Here's the dependency and [a link to download the JAR](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.3/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but now i am getting error as     Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     can you send me hive-site.xml file. Which property should i write in hive-site.xml for  hive server 2

Comment: Cloudera's Hive JDBC driver comes with a well-written documentation. Follow it and you should be able to solve this because that is out of scope for your current question.

Comment: And mark this answer as THE answer :)